# add ruby options to rails link_to helper

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

According to the rails doc, this is how one uses the link_to tag in erb file.

```
<%= link_to(body, url, html_options = {}) %>
```

Wondering whether there is a way to put a yield tag inside link_to helper tag
I was hoping to be able to do something like

```
<%= link_to(body, url, yield(:something)) %>
```

Well, I tried the above but had no luck.

Comment: so you just want to be able to pass in different html_options based on some param? What about creating a view helper for that page?

Comment: You've got the link as it appears on the page (`body`), and what it links to (`url`). What is left for the yielded stuff to do?

Comment: In my case I have a navbar on my html page which I am rendering across all the pages of my application, I would like to yield a style so that when a link is clicked, the navbar of that page becomes the active. So the yield would be some css class.